# WiFi router with API (indoor positioning)

Tags: indoor-positioning-system

I try to figure out how to create simple positioning system using WiFi. I need to get RSSI (Received signal strength indication) value between router and client. Are there any routers which have API, e.g. REST interface to "ask" them about their client and their signal strength? If no, what are other possibilities to get these data?

Comment: Check your router manofacturer and model, from there you might know how to communicate with that router version (if possible). Some routers do not allow this communication, but almost all routers out there have a OS with which you can interact. Also you might visit [dd-wrt](http://dd-wrt.com/site/index) for further options using the router hardware.

Comment: We can assume that I don't have router. I'm looking for hardware which is easy to communicate with.

Comment: Then about hardware [arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) or [raspberrypi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) might be very helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Indoor Positioning, but i'm learning from scratch to be able to do a thesis to graduate from my local public university.

I've read a lot, so I can assure you that in order to create a simple positioning system using Wi-Fi you really don't need access to the router or even know the AP location. (Please read this work https://www.zotero.org/amcallejas/items/collectionKey/K6CDB2CR/itemKey/NDED9X7K and feel free to explore my Zotero library)

What you need is to access the RSS in the device. For example, if you're on an Android device, you should use the Android API "WiFi Manager" (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) and then write some code ;)

I cannot comment on Stackoverflow yet, so I hope this "answer" helps.

PS. Sorry for my bad English